# Calling bootstrap function in a dynamic anchor control

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

This may be a stupid question but I hope you guys can help me. I want to produce this kind of dynamic anchor.

```
<a href="#Login" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>
```

And I have this code:

```
HtmlAnchor login = new HtmlAnchor();
//login.data-toggle = "modal";
login_pos.Controls.Add(login);
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using c# not JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to add the "data-toggle" attribute to the HtmlAnchor control, you should be able to do the following:

```
 HtmlAnchor login = new HtmlAnchor();
 login.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
 login_pos.Controls.Add(login);
```

Comment: Glad to help, please do not forget to check this as the correct answer :)